# ROMP : Creating avatar on the live cam window

Tags: python, 3d, mesh

I was testing the [ROMP project](https://github.com/Arthur151/ROMP/), in which i tested its webcam pipeline and it was generating a cartoon character as show below
[image: Cartoon Character]

But the main issue is that this pipeline is creating 2 different windows : one for live webcam and second for this character mesh. My aim is to create this character on the webcam window.

I have gone through multiple files and found that webcam window is being generated by opencv imshow in  file webcam.py and for the cartoon character it is being generated by the open3d-visualizer file in romp.lib.utils.open3d_visualizer.py
I have posted an issue in github but didn't get any response so i thought to post it here as well.